# How copy, paste, delete files or documents with Winium Desktop c#

Tags: c#, automation, winium

I´m using Winium Desktop to create a little bot, It opens programs correctly, but I need to handle files too, copy them to a specific path in the local machine and read an Excel file (they have .pdf and .xlsx extension). How could I do it? (sorry for my bad English)

I'm running Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe in local machine. it provide a server in localhost port 9999.

```
DesktopOptions options = new DesktopOptions();
options.ApplicationPath = "<<application path>>";
WiniumDriver dr=new WiniumDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9999"), options);
//Here need to copy files from a directory to another one before continue.
```

Comment: something to remember...that just because u have UI automation does not mean part of the process cannot be just standard code...you still have the whole system.io namespace available to you to use

Comment: I understand, but, Can I execute system.io instructions in a remote driver like Winium?